# "<class name> does not provide a call operator" error when trying to wrap function return value

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-function

I'm trying to write a function that will take a functor as an argument, invoke the functor and then return its return value wrapped in a `boost::shared_ptr`.

The following refuses to compile and I'm all out of ideas. I get "std::vector< std::string > does not provide a call operator" (roughly). I'm using Clang 3.1 on Mac OS X.

```
template< typename T >
boost::shared_ptr< T > ReturnValueAsShared(
    boost::function< T() > func )
{
  return boost::make_shared< T >( func() );
}
```

This is the context in which I'm trying to use it:

```
make_shared< packaged_task< boost::shared_ptr< std::vector< std::string > > > >(
   bind( ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >,
      bind( [a function that returns a std::vector< std::string >] ) ) );
```

EDIT: Here's a complete self-contained test case. This code fails to compile with the same error, and for the life of me I can't see what's wrong:

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::string > foo( std::string a )
{
  std::vector< std::string > vec;
  vec.push_back( a );
  return vec;
}

template< typename T >
boost::shared_ptr< T > ReturnValueAsShared(
    boost::function< T() > func )
{
  return boost::make_shared< T >( func() );
}

int main()
{
  auto f = boost::bind( ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >,
                        boost::bind( foo, std::string("a") ) );
  f();

} // main
```

And here's the error output:

```
In file included from testcase.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/function.hpp:64:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:13:
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132:18: error: type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >' does not provide a call operator
          return (*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS);
                 ^~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:907:53: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker0<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >::invoke' requested here
        { { &manager_type::manage }, &invoker_type::invoke };
                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::function0<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >::assign_to<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >' requested here
      this->assign_to(f);
            ^
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1042:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::function0<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >::function0<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >' requested here
    base_type(f)
    ^
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:243:43: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::function<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > ()>::function<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >' requested here
        return unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > (*)(std::basic_string<char>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<std::basic_string<char> > > > >::operator()<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > > (*)(boost::function<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > ()>), boost::_bi::list0>' requested here
        BOOST_BIND_RETURN l_(type<result_type>(), f_, a, 0);
                          ^
testcase.cpp:27:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > > (*)(boost::function<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > ()>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::bind_t<std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > > (*)(std::basic_string<char>), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<std::basic_string<char> > > > > >::operator()' requested here
  f();
   ^
1 error generated.
```

Here are some more clues. The following code compiles just fine, but that doesn't help me since this is not the code that I want :)

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::string > foo()
{
  std::vector< std::string > vec;
  return vec;
}

template< typename T >
boost::shared_ptr< T > ReturnValueAsShared(
    boost::function< T() > func )
{
  return boost::make_shared< T >( func() );
}

int main()
{
  auto f = boost::bind( ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >,
                        foo );
  f();

} // main
```

Comment: Please simplify the problem and provide a minimal (non-)working example code.

Comment: @KerrekSB The error is `std::vector<std::string> does not provide a call operator` when I try to use it as `ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'll try to minimize it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Test case added.

Comment: The parameter `boost::function< T() > func` - maybe it should have `T` instead of `T()` ?

Comment: @user1071136 No, that fails to compile as well (as it should) since that's not the way that boost::function accepts function definitions. See [the Boost.Function docs.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1545628)

Comment: Hm, looks like Boost just isn't that good. The `std` version of this works as soon as you add an explicit conversion to `std::function<std::vector<std::string>>()>` around the `bind` call.

Comment: @KerrekSB Are you saying this is a Boost bug? I was leaning towards that conclusion...

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried wrapping the second `bind` call with `boost::function< std::vector< std::string >() >()` to cast it and it now compiles. Kerrek, make your comment an answer and I'll accept it since it led me down the right path (I just used the `boost::` version of what you said).

Comment: Strange behaviour...

http://liveworkspace.org/code/2c2b09f708a6d481e06aa39f2eda632f

compiler try to convert int to boost::function<int()>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some constructions (such as `bind`) return intermediate "expression" types which you don't actually want to capture on the nose. In that case, you mustn't capture the type via `auto`, and you may need to specify explicit conversions, since otherwise there isn't a unique, single user-defined conversion chain. In your case, add the explicit conversion from the bind expression to `function`:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> G;
auto f = boost::bind(ReturnValueAsShared<G>,
             static_cast<boost::function<G()>(boost::bind(foo, std::string("a")))
                    );
```

(This itself doesn't actually work for me, but it does work if you use the corresponding `std` construc­tions.)

Comment: Wrapping my second `bind` call with a cast `boost::function< std::vector< std::string >() >(...)` makes everything work right. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

boost::protect is the way to go:

```
int main()
{
  auto f = boost::bind( ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >,
                        boost::protect(boost::bind( foo, std::string("a") ) ) );
  f();

} // main
```

This is as clean as it can get.

Comment: This answer could be improved by an explanation of what `boost::protect` is, what it does and maybe a link to the docs that describe it in even more detail.

Answer (score 2):

*Complete rewrite, original answer was incorrect.*

## Error analysis

As I didn't know at first what was going wrong here, I did some analysis. I'm keeping it for future reference; see the solution below for how to avoid the problem.

`bind.hpp` does this:

```
return unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
```

which in my opinion translates like this:

```
unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0) = ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >
base_type::a1_ = boost::bind( foo, std::string("a") )
```

So what you would expect this code to do is pass the argument to the function, just the way it is. But for this to work, the expression `a[base_type::a1_]` would have to be of type `boots:_bi::value<T>`, whereas it is of the unwrapped type `boost::_bi::bind_t`. So instead of the functor being passed as the argument, a special overloaded version gets called:

```
namespace boost { namespace _bi { class list0 {
    …
    template<class R, class F, class L>
    typename result_traits<R, F>::type
    operator[] (bind_t<R, F, L> & b) const {
        return b.eval(*this);
    }
    …
} } }
```

This will *evaluate* the nullary function, instead of passing it on. So instead of an object returning a vector, the argument now is a vecotr. Subsequent steps will attempt to convert that to a `boost::function` and fail.

## Canonical solution

*Edited yet again:*
It looks like this special handling of [nested binds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds) is intended as a feature. Talking on `#boost` with users Zao and heller, I now know that there is a `protect` function to counter these effects. So the canonical solution to this problem appears to be the following:

```
…
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
…
  auto f = boost::bind( ReturnValueAsShared< std::vector< std::string > >,
    boost::protect ( boost::bind( foo, std::string("a") ) ) );
…
```

Comment: No, the returned value is a functor that when executed returns a `shared_ptr`. If I replace `f()` with `(*f)()`, I rightly get a compiler error that complains that `f` is not of pointer type.

Comment: OK, You are rtight, the problem is one level deeper. It appears to me that `bind` has no overloading for `shared_ptr`, so it assumes a function object by default. But as `shared_ptr` doesn't provide a call operator, things fail.

Comment: Um, `bind` doesn't need an overload for `shared_ptr`, it's a template. Also, the error complains that `vector<string>` doesn't have a call operator, not a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: For your edited version: you seem to be missing that there is a `boost::bind(` in front of `ReturnValueAsShared` in `auto f = ...`. At no point does the code try to call `shared_ptr<...>::operator()`.

Comment: OK, that about the `vector<string>` is a good point. I'll leave my answer around for the time being, as a documentation of failed efforts, but expect to delete it eventually once a proper answer could be found.

Comment: @Lucas: Second major edit, completely rewrote the code. Got it to work.

Comment: @Lucas, I edited the answer yet again; now it includes the canonical solution as found in the boost documentation.